# OnSubmit with Mobile Safari

Tags: jquery, iphone, webkit, mobile-safari, onsubmit

While using [jCart](http://conceptlogic.com/jcart/) I noticed that it did not work on the iPhone. After some testing (and speaking with the developer on the [jcart forum](http://conceptlogic.com/jcart/help/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=316) ) it seems that it fails to call the submit handler when clicking a submit button:

```
$('form.jcart').submit(function(){...});
```

I have tried changing this to:

```
$("form.jcart input[type='submit']").click(function(){...});
// There were some other code changes needed to make this change work,
// but they are omitted for brevity (they don't impact the problem).
```

This too does not work. I have found other reports of having problems with .submit/onsubmit on the iPhone, but it doesn't seem like anyone has found a work around for it?

Comment: Maybe try changing the type from submit to button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jonathan: I solved the problem we were having. As it turns out, some supplementary code was the source of the issue, and by removing it, everything works normally on the iPhone, iPod Touch.

I've described the solution back on the jCart forum:
http://conceptlogic.com/jcart/help/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=316&start=10